# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas_profiling' after pip install

Tags: python-3.x, pip, jupyter-notebook, pandas-profiling, llvmlite

I have tried to install pandas profiling using pip in a Jupyter notebook with python 3.6.

I get the following output for all install attempts I have tried:

- install output:

[image]

I have tried:
 !pip install pandas-profiling
 !pip install pandas-profiling[notebook]

import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install pandas-profiling

Additionally, I have restarted the kernal after each attempt.

I imagine it has something to do with 'llvmlite' but I am not sure. How can I successfully install and import the package?

Comment: Have you tried creating a new conda/pip environment?